# Persisting date and nested with JSON

Tags: grails

I'm trying to save nested person, which is json array and complains about requiring a Set.

Another problem I encountered, is that another field date cannot be null, but contains value already.

What I need to do before for adding params into my object or I have to change my json is built? I'm trying to save json post like this:

```
// relationship of Test
//static hasMany = [people: Person, samples: Sample]

def jsonParams= JSON.parse(request.JSON.toString())
def testInstance= new Test(jsonParams)

//Error requiring a Set
[Failed to convert property value of type 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'people'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.Person] for property 'people[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
//error saying its null
Field error in object 'com.Test' on field 'samples[2].dateTime': rejected value [null]; codes [com.Sample]

//...
"samples[0].dateTime_hour":"0",
"samples[0].dateTime_minute":"0",
"samples[0].dateTime_day":"1",
"samples[0].dateTime_month":"0",
"samples[0].dateTime_year":"-1899",
"samples[0]":{  
  "dateTime_minute":"0",
  "dateTime_day":"1",
  "dateTime_year":"-1899",
  "dateTime_hour":"0",
  "dateTime_month":"0"
},
"people":[  
  "1137",
  "1141"
], //...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, ths line is unnecessary:

```
def jsonParams= JSON.parse(request.JSON.toString())
```

The `request.JSON` can be directly passed to the `Test` constructor:

```
def testInstance = new Test(request.JSON)
```

---

I'm not sure what your `Person` class looks like, but I'm assuming those numbers (1137, 1141) are ids.  If that is the case, then your json should work - there's a chance that passing the `request.JSON` directly could help.  I tested your JSON locally and it has no problem associating the `hasMany` collection.  I also used:

```
// JSON numbers rather than strings
"people": [1137, 1141]

// using Person map with the id
"people: [{
    "id": 1137
}, {
    "id": 1141
}]
```

Both of these worked as well and are worth trying.

---

Concerning the null `dateTime`, I would rework your JSON.  I would send the `dateTime` in a single field, instead of splitting the value into hour/minute/day/etc.  The default formats are `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` and `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'`, but these can be defined by the `grails.databinding.dateFormats` config setting (`config.groovy`).  There are other ways to do the binding as well (`@BindingFormat` annotation) but it's going to be easiest to just send the date in a way that grails can handle without additional configuration.

If you are dead set on splitting the `dateTime` into pieces, then you could use the `@BindUsing` annotation:

```
class Sample{
    @BindUsing({obj, source ->   
        def hour = source['dateTime_hour']
        def minute = source['dateTime_minute']
        ...
        // set obj.dateTime based on these pieces
    })
    Date dateTime
}
```

---

An additional comment on your JSON, you seem to have `samples[0]` defined twice and are using 2 syntaxes for your internal collections (JSON arrays and indexed keys).  I personally would stick with a single syntax to clean it up:

```
"samples": [  
  {"dateTime": "1988-01-01..."}
  {"dateTime": "2015-10-21..."}
],"people": [  
  {"id": "1137"},
  {"id": "1141"}
],
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I could that